# Adjacency lists in Java

Tags: java, adjacency-list

I have an adjacency table. See above:

```
e1.p1.x     e1.p1.y     e1.p2.x     e1.p2.y
x1 46       y1 280      x2 346      y2 339
x1 331      y1 229      x2 46       y2 280
x1 1        y1 74       x2 207      y2 325
x1 388      y1 29       x2 1        y2 74
x1 237      y1 72       x2 46       y2 280
x1 346      y1 339      x2 331      y2 229
x1 46       y1 280      x2 331      y2 229
x1 207      y1 325      x2 101      y2 152
x1 132      y1 55       x2 46       y2 280
x1 101      y1 152      x2 1        y2 74
x1 331      y1 229      x2 346      y2 339
x1 346      y1 339      x2 101      y2 152
x1 101      y1 152      x2 132      y2 55
x1 346      y1 339      x2 1        y2 74
x1 237      y1 72       x2 132      y2 55
x1 331      y1 229      x2 207      y2 325
```

There are 2 points in each row, which are neighbours. I would like to make lists like this, with all the neighbors of each point. But I get also fake adjacencies, I get more adjacencies in list above, than represented in the table.

```
    Output:
    [207, 325, 0, 1, 74, 0, 101, 152, 0, 331, 229, 0]
    [331, 229, 0, 46, 280, 0, 346, 339, 0, 207, 325, 0]
    [46, 280, 0, 346, 339, 0, 331, 229, 0, 237, 72, 0, 132, 55, 0]
    [346, 339, 0, 46, 280, 0, 331, 229, 0, 101, 152, 0, 1, 74, 0]
    [101, 152, 0, 207, 325, 0, 1, 74, 0, 346, 339, 0, 132, 55, 0]
    [132, 55, 0, 46, 280, 0, 101, 152, 0, 237, 72, 0]
    [237, 72, 0, 46, 280, 0, 132, 55, 0]
    [1, 74, 0, 207, 325, 0, 388, 29, 0, 101, 152, 0, 346, 339, 0]
    [388, 29, 0, 1, 74, 0]
```

This is Java code:

```
for (j = 0; j < size; j++) {
    ArrayList < Integer > aList = adjLists.get(j);
    for (Edge e: edges) {
        if ((points[j][0] == e.p1.x && points[j][1] == e.p1.y)) {
            aList.add(e.p1.x);
            aList.add(e.p1.y);
            aList.add(0);

            for (Edge e1: edges) {
                if (e1.p1.x == e.p1.x && e1.p1.y == e.p1.y && !aList.contains(e1.p2.x) && !aList.contains(e1.p2.y)) {
                    aList.add(e1.p2.x);
                    aList.add(e1.p2.y);
                    aList.add(0);

                }
            }
            break;
        }

        if ((points[j][0] == e.p2.x && points[j][1] == e.p2.y)) {

            aList.add(e.p2.x);
            aList.add(e.p2.y);
            aList.add(0);
            for (Edge e1: edges) {
                if (e1.p2.x == e.p1.x && e1.p2.y == e.p1.y && !aList.contains(e1.p1.x) && !aList.contains(e1.p1.y)) {
                    aList.add(e1.p1.x);
                    aList.add(e1.p1.y);
                    aList.add(0);
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Size is the number of vertices, aList should store adjacencies.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Yeah, sure! What causes false adjacencies, with use of code above?

Comment: I understand your question, could you provide a full working example of the code, for easier debugging? (That is, the code for "edges", "points" and "adjLists".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the correct way to do this is to define a class Point instead of using raw integers:

```
 class Point {
   private final int x;
   private final int y;
   Point(int x, int y) {this.x = x; this.y = y;}
   int getX() {return x;}
   int getY() {return y;}
 }
```

Then an adjacency list is:

```
Map<Point, Set<Point>> adjacencies;
```

Then to use it you just write;

```
for (/* rows */) {
  Point pt1 = new Point(x1, y1); // Extract from the table.
  Point pt2 = new Point(x2, y2); // Extract from the table.
  Set<Point> adjs = adjacencies.find(pt1);
  if (adjs == null) {
    adjs = new HashSet<Point>();
    adjacencies.put(pt1, adjs);
  }
  adjs.put(pt2);
  // Same for pt2
}
```

This way you can get the adjacencies of a point as follows:

```
Set<Point> adjs = asjacencies.get(point);
```

Much easier than searching an array of arrays and parsing every two into a point.

If some other module needs the data in the form of an array of arrays you can do as follows:

```
List<List<Integer>> toLists(Map<Set<Point>> adjacencies) {
  List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
  for (Point pt : adjacencies.getKeys()) {
    List<Integer> adjs = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    adjs.add(pt.getX());
    adjs.add(pt.getY());
    adjs.add(0);
    for (Point adjPt : adjacencies.get(pt)) {
      adjs.add(adjPt.getX());
      adjs.add(adjPt.getY());
      adjs.add(0);
    }
    result.add(adjs);
  }
  return result; 
}
```

Comment: How one will get the x and y values without the getters?

Comment: Maybe, but other part of my code uses this as an input. So fixing of this code would be great and reduce time consumption of development.

Comment: I added getters to Point. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Good design saves much more time than good debugging.

Comment: I do not need getters, values are in arrays, but NOT only the correct values.

Comment: If the other part of the code requires a different design you can easily write an adapter function. I will edit my response.

Comment: Last code isn't doing the same function, that my code....

Comment: It does not make easier the search for adjacent points.

Comment: Why not it is just get instead of iteration. It's also more efficient at O(1) instead of O(n).

Comment: Can you please show me a code exactly instead of my? Because first of all it doesn't insert zeros.

Comment: What do the zeros mean? I added zeros.

Comment: These are flags, store state of point. But fixing my code would be much more greater! I am curious what is my fault. :)